# Continuous flow of songs in my javaFX media player

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create an mp3 player in javaFX, basically all is working as it is supposed to be, I just have one problem. I can't figure out, how should I implement if one song stops playing, how to make another one start playing.
I have the code connected to a database, the database has a table of songs(name, album, artist, path).

This is a method in my SongsIO class, which basically starts playing the song, by accepting its name.

```
public void playSong(String name) {


    String path = getPathByName(name);
    Media hit = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

This is the method from my Controller class, that gets the song name from a ListView and passes it to the playSong method from SongsIO

```
@FXML
public void playSong() {
    String songName = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    playingLabel.setText(songName);
    SongsIO.getInstance().playSong(songName);
}
```

Now I just don't know, how to set up a method, or a listener or something, which would be calling my playNextSong method, to play a next song from the listView.

Thank you.

Comment: The [`MediaPlayer`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) class has many properties for listening to various state.

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to connect it... How to add to the program, that it constantly listens to the change from MediaPlayer.status.PLAYING to MediaPlayer.status.PAUSED